# Get Room/Resources from Office 365

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api

Looking for a way to access office 365 and get all the resources/mailboxes of rooms.  We have tried following, all are pretty involved.

1. getRooms/getRoomsList: requires the room list is configured, if not, returns null.
2. AD REST API: never returns anything that says the mailbox is type resource/room ...
3. SOAP API: still experimenting, but not able to find any filter for rooms.
4. LDAP: O365 seems not supporting LDAP, there are documentations this may work using power shell.

The software we are developing is a web service, using power shell is not an option.

Any ideas on how to do this? or this is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you should build a service app like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx .So far, i think this is the only way to access all the data as you want

Comment: What will be the API to call to get all the rooms?

Comment: Send a Get request to this one: https://graph.windows.net/yourcompany.onmicrosoft.com/groups?api-version=2013-04-05

With headers: 
Accept : application/json 
Authorization : Bearer (AccessToken)